# Solr Unable to Index and Query List of Object with Key Value Pairs

Tags: solr, solrj

Im trying to index a set of documents which contains a list of objects with key value pairs. I was able to index the documents bt unable to query the documents as solr not returning any results.

Please help me with this.

My Sample Data Source:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b856d762aa4df47ec47d265"),
    "interestgroups" : [],
    "emailId" : "2015msunitedstates@gmail.com",
    "mkmdata" : [ 
        {
            "visitTime" : [ 
                ISODate("1899-12-31T18:30:00.000Z")
            ],
            "city" : ["a","b"],
            "source" : [ 
                "Direct-1",
                "Direct"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "visitTime" : [ 
                ISODate("2017-07-12T08:36:11.000Z")
            ],
            "city" : [ 
                "Miami"
            ],
            "source" : [ 
                "Email"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Below is my schema.xml

```
<field name="mkmdata" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="mkmdata.city" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="mkmdata.source" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

My Query

```
q=emailId:2015msunitedstates@gmail.com&fq=mkmdata.source:Email
```

My Indexed document is in the following format

```
[
      {
        "mkmdata": [
          "{ \"visitTime\" : [ { \"$date\" : \"1899-12-31T18:30:00.000Z\"}] , \"city\" : [ ] ,\"source\" : [ \"Direct-1\",\"Direct\"] }",
          "{ \"visitTime\" : [ { \"$date\" : \"2017-07-12T08:36:11.000Z\"}] , \"city\" : [ \"Miami\"] , \"source\" : [ \"Email\"] }"
        ],
        "emailId": "2015msunitedstates@gmail.com",
        "id": "5b856d762aa4df47ec47d265",
      }
    ]
```

Comment: How are you querying? What results do you expect? What does the document look like in the index?

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh. 
How are you querying?
My Query is q=emailId:2015msunitedstates@gmail.com&fq=mkmdata.source:Email
What results do you expect?
I want to return the result matched with mkmdata.source
What does the document look like in the index?
Its converting the object as string object

Comment: Add the relevant data to your question, and include how the document actually looks in the Index, since that's what's relevant for the query. Solr does not support multi level JSON directly (the `.` syntax is default for Elasticsearch iirc).

Comment: @MatsLindh Updated the data after indexing in my question. Please have a look and help me with my issue

Comment: The "mkmdata" field has been indexed as a single, textual value. To be able to query the values in each field, you'll have to split it into separate fields. I'm not sure how you do (if you even can) that with with the POJO mapping. My solution (with limited knowledge of SolrJ) would be to index the document manually and build the list of fields manually.

Comment: @MatsLindh. I have indexed "mkmdata" field as a text and individual fields im "mkmdata" as "mkmdata.source" is it what your trying to tell. If yes, I did but its not working

Comment: No, that's not what I'm trying to tell you. What I'm trying to say is that you have a _single_ text value in the field `mkmdata` (which has been sent over as serialized JSON structure). There are no other fields named anything with `mkmdata` (so no `mkmdata.source` field) in your document - Solr documents are flat by default (there are ways around that with child/parent documents and blockjoins, but it'll complicate your queries and indexing process).